Using std::condition_variable with custom (spin) mutex?
I'm encountering difficulties using std::condition_variable with my custom spin mutex implementation. It seems that std::condition_variable expects a std::mutex to be associated with its lock, leading to compilation errors when attempting to use a different mutex implementation.
Here's a simplified version of my code where the compilation error occurs:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class SpinMutex {
public:
    void lock() {
        // Implement spin lock logic here
    }

    void unlock() {
        // Implement spin unlock logic here
    }

private:
    // Implement atomic flag or other spin lock mechanism here
};

SpinMutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void worker_thread() {
    // Do some work...
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // Attempting to lock a SpinMutex with std::lock_guard
    // This line will throw a compilation error
    std::unique_lock<SpinMutex> lock(mutex);

    ready = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);

    {
        std::unique_lock<SpinMutex> lock(mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [] { return ready; });
    }

    worker.join();
    return 0;
}

As shown, the use of std::unique_lock with SpinMutex throws a compilation error. It appears that std::condition_variable is tightly coupled with std::mutex, making it incompatible with custom mutex implementations like a spin mutex.
I think I can use std::condition_variable_any but my question is why the standard decided to go this way? Is it because of legacy purposes or because they implement a special optimization for std::mutex. In other words, for a non-genius developer e.g. SpinMutex above, can I guarantee that std::mutex will outperform my own implementation in general?
VS Implementation capture


I have added a capture of VS Implementation in question condition variable takes only standard mutex. My question is about my own implementation of mutex not unique mutex or any inheriting class from standard mutex and also reference confirms the same https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable i.e. condition variable only supports standard mutex. The question about performance is linked to my original question because if condition variable only supports standard mutex, then maybe there is an  optimization I can not outperform

As to "why". std::condition_variable may provide better performance; since all parts are within the standard library implementation, there could be secret sauce, e.g. directly using OS-provided primitives.

That is what I wanted to confirm, thank you!


I think I can use std::condition_variable_any

Yes, correct.

but my question is why the standard decided to go this way?

The purpose of the synchronization API's in C++ is to provide a portable wrapper around OS synchronization API's.  And the design of the C++ API was highly influenced by the Linux pthreads API.
So std::mutex and std::condition_variable are meant to be as thin wrappers as possible around the underlying OS API.  In terms of pthreads, std::mutex maps to pthread_mutex_t.  And std::condition_variable maps to pthread_cond_t.
And a pthread_cond_t waits on a pthread_mutex_t.  But at the time it was realized that:

It is reasonable to want to wait on something besides a std::mutex, and
It will be more expensive to wait on a generalized concept of mutex than on a std::mutex.

Thus std::condition_variable_any was designed to meet the needs of those wanting to wait on a generalized mutex concept while not making those who don't need that generality pay for the feature.
Here is an early paper with the design rationale:
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#condition
What this paper calls cond_var was eventually renamed to condition_variable.  And what this paper calls gen_cond_var was eventually renamed to condition_variable_any.
Also of note: this paper goes into detail about the difficulty of implementing gen_cond_var. However a bug still existed in this paper's implementation.  It was more difficult than even the authors realized at the time.  However all major implementations of std::condition_variable_any are bug free as of C++11 as far as I know.
